# The type initializer for threw an exception in entity framework model?

Tags: .net, entity-framework

I have 2 projects A and B
each project has its own database and connect to it using entity framework and each project is working well alone
My problem is that when I use the project B as a library inside the project A It gives me "The type initializer for (MYCLASS) threw an exception"
you should know that (MYCLASS): is an Entity inside the project B

Comment: Is the connection string of B's context in the app.config of A?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check if both projects are referring to the same version of entityframework in `app.config`.
You might have upgraded your ef dlls in your project B but not in your project A. Since you have made reference of B in A, entityframework is using the config in A for both projects.

Answer (score 1):

Install same version of EF to all project first and then check the following in the App.config file,

1. **connectionStrings** element is after the **configSections** element.
2. **startup** element is after the **connectionStrings** element.

> 

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <configuration>
   <configSections>
         <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=4.3.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
   </configSections>
   <connectionStrings>
         <add name="SchedulingContext" connectionString="Data Source=XXX\SQL2008R2DEV;Initial Catalog=YYY;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=XXX"   providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
   </connectionStrings>
   <startup>
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
  </startup>       
 </configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

just remove all lines from ConfigSection

```
 <configSections>
<!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
<section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=4.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
```